# Importing from NPM packages using a path to a component

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-package

When using Material UI, I can import modules in two ways:

```js
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
// or
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
```

I reviewed their source code [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/packages/mui-material) and I noticed their project is structured as this

```
/mui-material
  | package.json
  | tsconfig.json
  / src
    | <components>
    | index.js
```

(I skipped some files in order not to lose a big picture)

I've been working on my personal npm package structured in a similar way. I managed to successfully push it to my NPM feed, but when I use it from another project I can import it in the following way:

```js
import { MyModule } from '@la27/utils';
// or
import MyModule from '@la27/utils/src/MyModule';
```

How can I change it so that I don't need to use the "src" part?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `index.js` file within `utils` directory, and export the component in the `index.js` file as following:

```
// this is the example for Material UI's Box component. Change it accordingly:

export { default as Box } from './Box';
export * from './Box';
```

Reference the Material UI's own `index.js` file here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/index.js

Upvote would be appreciated if this was helpful!